# Why is osgEarth not building with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, osgearth

I'm trying to build osgEarth with Quarts. Instructions on the official website reads:

> Point the QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE CMake variable to the qmake.exe you want
>   to use and CMake will populate all the other QT variables.

Good. I do the following:

```
cmake -D QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/bin/qmake CMakeLists.txt 
make
```

And get the following error:

```
[ 19%] Built target osgEarth
[ 25%] Built target osgEarthSymbology
[ 32%] Built target osgEarthFeatures
[ 35%] Built target osgEarthAnnotation
[ 44%] Built target osgEarthUtil
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/osgEarthQt/CMakeFiles/osgEarthQt5.dir/ViewerWidget.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/garbart/Desktop/osgearth-master/src/osgEarthQt/ViewerWidget.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGui:45:
In file included from /Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopenglcontext.h:61:
/Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopenglversionfunctions.h:1089:23: error: 
      unknown type name 'GLDEBUGPROC'
    QT_OPENGL_DECLARE(QT_OPENGL_4_3_FUNCTIONS);
                      ^
In file included from /Users/garbart/Desktop/osgearth-master/src/osgEarthQt/ViewerWidget.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGui:47:
/Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopenglextrafunctions.h:472:33: error: 
      unknown type name 'GLDEBUGPROC'
    void glDebugMessageCallback(GLDEBUGPROC callback, const void *userParam);
                                ^
/Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopenglextrafunctions.h:758:23: error: 
      unknown type name 'GLDEBUGPROC'
    QT_OPENGL_DECLARE(QT_OPENGL_EXTRA_FUNCTIONS)
                      ^
/Users/garbart/Qt/5.10.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/qopenglextrafunctions.h:2213:59: error: 
      unknown type name 'GLDEBUGPROC'
inline void QOpenGLExtraFunctions::glDebugMessageCallback(GLDEBUGPROC ca...
                                                          ^
4 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [src/osgEarthQt/CMakeFiles/osgEarthQt5.dir/ViewerWidget.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/osgEarthQt/CMakeFiles/osgEarthQt5.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

QT 5.10.0
osgEarth 2.10

Comment: can you say what exactly fixed your issue from Damian's answer?

Comment: @chrisdembia I'm sorry for such long answer :( Me helped a configuration the build using `ccmake .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I build OSG, osgQt and osgEarth.

Obtain OSG, configure and build:

```
git clone --branch OpenSceneGraph-3.6.2 https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph.git

mkdir osg-build
cd osg-build
cmake ../OpenSceneGraph
make
sudo make install
```

Obtain osgQt, configure and build:

```
git clone https://github.com/openscenegraph/osgQt.git
mkdir osgqt-build
cd osgqt-build
cmake ../osgQt -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.6.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake
make
sudo make install
```

This last step may fail to build because osgQt is not keeping pace with OSG.

You will need to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` and set the directory paths for finding Qt and OSG. The `CMakeLists.txt` also hard references a particular version of OSG, this will need to modified. There has been quite a bit of discussion on the lists about these problems so this may have been sorted by the time you read this.

```
git clone https://github.com/gwaldron/osgearth.git
mkdir osgearth-build
cd osgearth-build
cmake ../osgearth -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.6.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake
```

Configure the build using `ccmake .` with the following settings:

```
OSGEARTH_QT_BUILD                ON  
OSGEARTH_QT_BUILD_LEGACY_WIDGE   ON
```

Build and install:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Note: Qt 5.11 should also work.

**Update 2 June 2020**

osgQt repository has changed a lot since my original post.

This means that the osgEarth 2.10 Qt will not build with osgQt. You will need to probably use the Qt4 tag.

Newer versions of osgEarth no longer have any Qt support.

The approach used to integrate OSG/osgEarth with Qt is a compromise at best.

I would suggest that creating a seperate OpenGL context which OSG/osgEarth uses to render into an offscreen buffer (two needed one for drawing into while the other is being displayed). The offscreen buffer is then displayed by Qt3D using a different OpenGL contex.

This is a more sensible approach as this would allow OSG/osgEarth to use multiple threads.

At the moment Qt and OSG/osgEarth are sharing the OpenGL context.

A starting point is the following post [https://embeddeddevelop.blogspot.com/2017/06/integrating-opengl-and-qtpainter.html] (disclaimer my blog).

Comment: @garbart can you say what exactly fixed your issue?

Comment: @chrisdembia; I think you will need to comment under the question to contact gerbart. Your comment came to me.

Comment: osgEarth support for Qt is deprecated at best now. The code is still in the repository but the build configuration has been removed from the cmake files.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install Qt.
2. Install latest openscengraph and ensure it works properly.
3. Then install latest osgEarth.

Please follow the order properly.

Comment: The latest OSG has Qt separated out. You will need to build OSG, osgQt and then osgEarth if you want to use the latest.